# EclEmma: Error while analyzing package fragment root

Tags: code-coverage, eclemma

I downloaded EclEmma 2.3.3 from Eclipse Marketplace to my Kepler Service Release 2. I ran a JUnit test with the test coverage option, but am getting the following error:

```
Error while loading coverage session (code 5001).
Error while analyzing package fragment root java at F/xxx/target/test-classes (code 5007).
Error while analyzing XXXClass.class.
```

I am able to run maven build and test within Eclipse with the Maven plugin and can also run tests as JUnit tests. The XXXClass file is not related to the test I ran the coverage on.

Comment: Even if `XXXClass.class` is unrelated to test, error happens on it, so will be hard to tackle error without knowing more about `XXXClass.class`.

Comment: @Blitz - Did you ever resolve this?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Godin I was able to resolve it. As far as I remember I had to remove the project with the XXXClass file. Try that and if it doesn't work (or you need that project) try to close all unrelated projects. Let me know how it goes.